# Shrub in open gravel field

Tags: species-identification, botany

- Location: Gravelly open field. East of Toronto.
- Date: August 4, 2022
- Description: Shrub; alternating leaves; 8 feet tall; trunk is 1.5 inches wide at the base.
- Tip: It's possible to zoom in on the photos by clicking them a couple of times

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost certainly Hawthorn (*[Crataegus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crataegus)*) genus. This is a fairly common genus of flowering and fruiting shrubs to small trees that produce white flowers in the spring and small red apple-shaped ([pome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pome)) fruit in autumn. Species are found wild all over the Northern Hemisphere and are invasive in a number of countries in the Southern Hemisphere.

They are characteristically quite thorny (as you can see in your photos 2 and 3), with the spikes being actually short stems. Leaves arise from the short spurs off stems and several species have deeply lobed and/or serrated leaves (leaves have both in your photos).

There are quite a few species, but which one this is, I don't know.